# Why are stack-traces missing from Sentry for javascript?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, sentry

We see lots of Javascript errors in Sentry that are missing a stack-trace, and not for older browsers where it isn't supported.

This makes it nearly impossible to diagnose what is causing the error. For example:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
  at ? (undefined:0)
```

This is happening in Safari 7.0.6 on OS X 10.9.5, according to the Sentry docs this should support stack-traces:

https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/#browser-compatibility

Comment: What version of raven-js?

Comment: @BenVinegar the latest, 3.1.1

Comment: I'm going to say this is an old browser issue. Sentry *should* record stack traces, but old browsers always create scenarios where it might bug out.